# change color calendar entries when past due date - SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, spcolor

I have a calendar that I want the shade color to change when it is already past the due date then would turn back to its normal color once the "status" has been set to submitted from the same list it is linked to. Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of view is this? Can't you use the column formatting of the modern view?

Comment: It is a calendar with a webpart list below it. This would be on classic view.  I would need the shade of the calendar entry to change depending on a condition.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add these details, so people don't have to read through all the comments to learn what you are asking.